# How to access nth element in a Haskell tuple

Tags: haskell, tuples, ghc

I have this:

```
 get3th (_,_,a,_,_,_) = a
```

which works fine in GHCI but I want to compile it with GHC and it gives error. If I want to write a function to get the nth element of a tuple and be able to run in GHC what should I do?
my all program is like below, what should I do with that?

```
 get3th (_,_,a,_,_,_) = a


 main = do 

    mytuple  <- getLine 
    print $  get3th mytuple
```

Comment: Note that it's usually a bad idea to ever use tuples larger than `(a,b)`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @AmiTavory: because you can't use `fst` and `snd` to access the elements. Ok, there are various library functions that generalise the job to larger tuples, but these require class polymorphism, which unnecessarily complicated things. Usually, when there are more than two elements to be handled, it's a good idea to make a suitable `data` record, this way it's clear what each field means. If you need this locally, you can also just _nest_ tuples; `((a,b),(c,d))` can be deconstructed with `fst` and `snd` alone.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Many thanks!

Comment: @leftaroundabout once your instructor hands you a list of 48 11-tuples to process for an assignment, you don't have a choice, you have to start with the huge tuple and no matter how you approach it, you end up having to type _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 2 times(for the conversion from the mutant tuple to a record format). It would be nice to have access to something to leave situations like this faster, preferably without having to type _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ twice(or more if you are adding the accesors manually). Im not making this up, that actually happened.

Comment: Surely it's possible to use show to put the mutant tuple into a String, parse it into  an Array of Arrays(for O(1) access), but this is expensive but still more sane than going through dealing with 11-uples using pattern matching.

Comment: @Dmitry an instructor who hands you a list of 11-tuples deserves to get the solution back in punchcard form. — No, `show` and parsing back such a tuple is even more insane than pattern-matching on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `getLine` gives you a `String`, but you want a tuple of some kind. You can fix your problem by converting the `String` to a tuple – for example by using the built-in `read` function. The third line here tries to parse the `String` into a six-tuple of `Int`s.

```
main = do
  mystring <- getLine

  let mytuple = read mystring :: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)

  print $ get3th mytuple
```

Note however that while this is useful for learning about types and such, you should never write this kind of code in practise. There are at least two warning signs:

1. You have a tuple with more than three or so elements. Such a tuple is very rarely needed and can often be replaced by a list, a vector or a custom data type. Tuples are rarely used more than temporarily to bring two kinds of data into one value. If you start using tuples often, think about whether or not you can create your own data type instead.
2. Using `read` to read a structure is not a good idea. `read` will explode your program with a terrible error message at any tiny little mistake, and that's usually not what you want. If you need to parse structures, it's a good idea to use a real parser. `read` can be enough for simple integers and such, but no more than that.

Comment: Re: point #2: there's also `readMaybe` now (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Text-Read.html#v%3areadMaybe), which won't blow up with a mistake

Comment: @amindfv Indeed, and I would suggest *always* using `readMaybe` or `readEither` instead of `read`. However, I still only recommend it for very simple values and no data structures.

Answer (score 0):

The type of getLine is `IO String`, so your program won't type check because you are supplying a `String` instead of a tuple.

Your program will work if proper parameter is supplied, i.e:

```
main = do 
  print $  get3th (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: Thats true it works in that way, but here how can I provide proper parameter for IO?

Comment: As mentioned by @leftaroundabout, tuples larges than (a,b) is a bad idea. If still you want go out with this, take six inputs in do block and supply them as a tuple to the function. (Or you can do some transformations of the String to six tuples according to your constraint.)

Comment: I am beginner in Haskell, you mean by " take six inputs in do block and supply them as a tuple to the function" means adding a let temp = my tuple ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your confusion is between tuples and lists. That is an understandable confusion when you first meet Haskell as many other languages only have one similar construct. Tuples use round parens: `(1,2)`. A tuple with n values in it is a type, and each value can be a different type which results in a different tuple type. So `(Int, Int)` is a different type from `(Int, Float)`, both are two tuples. There are some functions in the prelude which are polymorphic over two tuples, ie `fst :: (a,b) -> a` which takes the first element. `fst` is easy to define using pattern matching like your own function:

```
fst (a,b) = a
```

Note that `fst (1,2)` evaluates to `1`, but `fst (1,2,3)` is ill-typed and won't compile.

Now, lists on the other hand, can be of any length, including zero, and still be the same type; but each element must be of the same type. Lists use square brackets: `[1,2,3]`. The type for a list with elements of type `a` is written `[a]`. Lists are constructed from appending values onto the empty list `[]`, so a list with one element can be typed `[a]`, but this is syntactic sugar for `a:[]`, where `:` is the *cons* operator which appends a value to the head of the list. Like tuples can be pattern matched, you can use the empty list and the cons operator to pattern match:

```
head :: [a] -> a
head (x:xs) = x
```

The pattern match means `x` is of type `a` and `xs` is of type `[a]`, and it is the former we want for `head`. (This is a prelude function and there is an analogous function `tail`.)

Note that `head` is a partial function as we cannot define what it does in the case of the empty list. Calling it on an empty list will result in a runtime error as you can check for yourself in GHCi. A safer option is to use the Maybe type.

```
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead (x:xs) = Just x
safeHead [] = Nothing
```

`String` in Haskell is simply a synonym for `[Char]`. So all of these list functions can be used on strings, and `getLine` returns a `String`.

Now, in your case you want the 3rd element. There are a couple of ways you could do this, you could call `tail` a few times then call `head`, or you could pattern match like `(a:b:c:xs)`. But there is another utility function in the prelude, `(!!)` which gets the nth element. (Writing this function is a very good beginner exercise). So your program can be written

```
main = do
    myString <- getLine
    print $ myString !! 2  --zero indexed
```

Testing gives

```
Prelude> main
test
's'
```

So remember, tuples us `()`and are strictly of a given length, but can have members of different types; whereas lists use '[]', can be any length, but each element must be the same type. And `String`s are really lists of characters.

EDIT

As an aside, I thought I'd mention that there is a neater way of writing this main function if you are interested.

```
main = getLine >>= print . (!!3)
```